# Why does flutter not throw any errors after freezing?

Tags: flutter, debugging

I am new to Flutter, but I have quite a bit of experience in mobile apps overall. I am trying to implement a plugin into my flutter app.

My app runs as expected until I try to use a plugin. When I open the screen that uses this plugin the app freezes. The problem I have here is I don't get any errors logged as to what is the problem. The app simply freezes on my phone and the console does nothing leaving me no idea what went wrong.

This has happened quite a few times with different plugins I have used and I want to understand why I am not getting any errors? How am I supposed to debug my code when I don't get any errors logged? Is there someway that I can get flutter to display errors?

I don't want you to solve the problem in my code, but I want to understand how to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: freezing and crashing are very different things, so your title is quite misleading. Also nothing to do with Flutter itself. It can happen with native apps as well. And freezing is usually because of being in some kind of infinite loop. There technically isn't anything wrong with the code running then so there simply aren't any errors to log

Comment: @Ivo my app is freezing. I have updated the question so it is not misleading. That answers my question thank you!